# .Net Core How to new up a class using DI services?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

Is there a way to new up an arbitrary class by type (i.e. Activator.CreateInstance(myType) and have the .Net DI engine inject the dependencies for that type? I don't want to register instances of myType and myType can be any random type. I just want to be able to handle cases like:

```
myType(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

and have the DI inject the dependencies as expected. Doesn't happen through Activator obviously.

Comment: @TobiasTengler - you should probably post your comment as an answer since that's probably the best way to do this.

Comment: @TobiasTengler Yes sir! That was it. Been googling random terms all morning lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't support this out of the box, since it isn't connected to .NET Core's Dependency Injection in any way.

You should probably use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to instantiate your DI connected types.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [IGet](https://github.com/dotnet-IGet/IGet) to use the functionality of `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` in (maybe) better readable way.

At startup of your app, add:

```
serviceCollection.AddIGet();
```

Then get `IGet i` via dependency injection and use it like this:

```
var myClass = i.Get<MyClass>();
```

All the dependencies in the constructor of `MyClass` have been injected into `myClass`. (Make sure that all those dependencies are available in the serviceCollection or remove some of the dependencies from the constructor.)